# How to fit tiles into cells(isometric) in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, isometric

How do I fit tiles into a cell(isometric) in Unity? I have tried adjusting the pixels per unit of the artwork. The tiles don't fit exactly in a cell and I have noticed that they are at an angle to the cells too (Image 1). In the tile palette, some of the tiles are overlapping each other, they are occupying more than one cell. (Image 2)

[Tiles not fitting the cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slHzd.png)

[Overlapping tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkBaR.png)

Thanks for your replies

Comment: It doesnt look like you made your tiles the right shape - while I have never made tiles, one google later https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sn0Em90U7K0 has perfect run through on making tiles..

Comment: I am using a set made by KenneyNL

Comment: well they arent the right size for the grid you're using

Comment: Is there a way to make them fit?

Comment: you could probably stretch them all in photoshop or something

Answer (score 0):

Your tile should be the same size as the grid.  You can simply add a sprite to the scene to see if it fits or not

Comment: I couldn't get the sprite to fit into a cell

Comment: If you use default cell size for isometric grid (1, 0.5, 0) you just need create tiles like this http://prntscr.com/rh2ya5 . Size of this sprite is adapted for 100 pixel per unit